# Add enum field to Oracle DB in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, enums

I have an enum

```
public enum HourEmployeePOSITION_TYPE {
None,Cleaner,Waiter, Barmen, Barback, HeadWaiter, Manager, Assistant_Manager,General_Manager}
```

And this enum type is one of the fields of my entity`

```
 public class 
    HourEmployeeEntities {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private HourEmployeePOSITION_TYPE position;
```

What I'm trying to do is insert that entity to databse.

```
 connection = createConnection();
 statement = connection.createStatement();
 statement.execute("CREATE TABLE Employees(" +
                "id int," +
                " firstName varchar(60)," +
                " lastName varchar(60)," +
                " position varchar(60) not null check (position in ('None', 'Cleaner', 'Waiter', 'Barmen', 'Barback', 'HeadWaiter')))"
        );
```

But this way is not working, as it takes the valus as boolean.
`

Are there any other ways to insert my field with enum type into the Oracle DB?

Comment: where is `type` declared and how ?

Comment: 1. This is an Enum it doesn't require "type checking" the compiler takes care of it. 2. you can't insert "an enum" into the DB, but you can insert its string value by either using `.name()` or `.toString()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I suspect that using `ordinal` is not a good advice: if the enum will change in the future (additional types will be added) and the developer won't be careful enough to "add at the end" it will mess up the data.

Comment: @alfasin I've checked it now. The thing is that "not null check (position in" works as a boolean.So I guess it might work for 2 valus, but what if my enum type has 5 or 6 options?

Comment: @alfasin I am inserting values here:preparedStatement.setString(4, person.getPosition());
and getting sql.SQLDataException: Invalid character string format for type BOOLEAN

Comment: @VladDemyan that's exactly what I wrote: change `person.getPosition()` with `person.getPosition().name()` you have to do it because `position` is not a string (it's an enum), but `position.name()` is!

Comment: changed it to preparedStatement.setString(4,person.getPosition().name()); still same error message about boolean

Comment: @alfasin and getter seems good  public HourEmployeePOSITION_TYPE getPosition() {return position;}

Comment: It sounds like you defined `position` to be a boolean in the DB...

Comment: What do you mean with "*as it takes the valus as boolean*" the column is clearly a `varchar` (plus Oracle does not have a boolean data type in SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there is one in [PLSQL](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Boolean)

Comment: @alfasin: but not in SQL. And there is no PL/SQL in this question

Comment: @alfasin you were correct..such a stupid mistake:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to store enum in db as `int` and use following pattern in your code:

```
public interface HasIntId {
    int getId();
}
```

and enum `HourEmployeePositionType` will be:

```
public enum HourEmployeePositionType implements HasIntId {

    None(0),
    Cleaner(1),
    Waiter(2),
    Barmen(3),
    Barback(4),
    HeadWaiter(5),
    Manager(6),
    Assistant_Manager(7),
    General_Manager(8);

    private final int id;

    HourEmployeePositionType(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static HourEmployeePositionType getById(int id) {
         for (HourEmployeePositionType employeePositionType : HourEmployeePositionType.values()) {
             if (employeePositionType.getId == id) {
                 return employeePositionType;
             }
         }
         return HourEmployeePositionType.None;
    }
}
```